# How to enable sorting Data-table with i18n?

Tags: vuetify.js, vue-i18n, vuetify-datatable

I have a vuetify Data-table with multisort enabled like so:

```
<v-data-table
          ref="insuranceTable"
          :headers="headers"
          :items="getRows"
          :sort-by="['created']"
          :sort-desc="[true]"
          multi-sort
          :search="search"
          :items-per-page="10"          
        >
```

one of the columns in the table is `Insurance Type`. this value is fetched by using an index  like this `{{insuranceType[item.code]}}`. The insuranceType array is defined as follows:

```
insurancetype:[
 this.$t('insuranceType.life'),
 this.$t('insuranceType.health'),
 this.$t('insuranceType.property'),
]
```

The values are displayed in the data-table without any issue. However, When I try To sort the table by `Insurance Type` Column, nothing happens. The Sorting works for all other columns. The sorting works for `Insurance Type` column if I use a non i18n array like this:

```
insurancetype:['life','health','property']
```

How can I configure the `V-Data-Table` so it can be sorted by columns with i18n values?

Comment: You should feed the data table with `items` that have already mapped `code` to `insuranceType` - or provide a custom sorting function to the `sort` property in the column definition in `headers`, as shown in the [manual](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-headers)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom sorting function for the `Insurance Type` column in your headers array. I've used this method before to be able to sort some custom string dates formats like this:

```js
headers: [
   {
      text: 'Created date',
      value: 'created_at',
      align: 'center',
      sort: (a, b) => {
         var date1 = a.replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/, '$3/$2/$1')
         var date2 = b.replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/, '$3/$2/$1')

         return date1 < date2 ? -1 : 1
      }
   },
   ...
]
```

You should be able to add your own logic to be able to sort those. Can you replicate the issue in a codesanbox or codepen?